How to change alert style in .Net MAUI Android?
I am porting an application from Xamarin to .Net MAUI, In Xamarin I was using a light theme in Android, so the alerts had a white background but in MAUI the alerts have a gray background.
How can I change the alert background to have a white background?


To solve this issue first I created a "styles.xml" containing this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

  </style>
</resources>

Then I added the file to the directory Platforms/Android/Resources/values directory:

Then I set the Build Action to "AndroidResource"

The I edited the file "MainActivity.cs" to set the Theme "AppTheme"
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;

namespace MyAppMaui
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
    }
}

Done!, It worked

Do you have support for Dark theme in your application too?
